# How do I copy my pics on icloud to an external hard drive?

Tags: icloud, photos, external-disk, data-transfer

I'm trying to figure out how to back up my pictures on iCloud to an external hard drive.  Do I seriously have to do this one pic at a time?

Comment: Are you using a Mac or a PC?

Comment: @nohillside I would assume a mac...

Comment: @jbis not necessarily, people with PCs use iPhones as we. And can‘t use Photos to sync their photo library :-)

Comment: @nohillside Good point. https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht205323

Answer (score 1):

I opened Photos on my iMac running High Sierra 10.13.5. I then selected multiple photos using shift-click. Now go to the file menu and select Export and follow the directions. The last step lets you choose where to save the photos.